# In CQ/AEM, can I prevent Sidekick from showing?

Tags: javascript, aem

Under certain circumstances, I want to prevent the Sidekick from being displayed on a page. I tried some things:

- Removing the init.jsp include. This works, but it also prevents certain CQ javascript libraries from being loaded, and I need these libraries.
- Adding a jquery onload event to hide the sidekick.

  ```
  $(function() {CQ.WCM.getSidekick().hide()});
  ```

  This doesnt work because the sidekick isnt loaded yet.
- Adding a jquery onload event with a timeout.

  ```
  $(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      CQ.WCM.getSidekick().hide(); 
    }, 1)
  });
  ```

  But this is not reliable. Setting the timeout too low will have a high chance of failure. Setting it too high will cause it to appear then disappear, which is unacceptable.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways to achieve this.

If you want the sidekick to be unavailable in all the pages, just comment out the following piece of code available in the init.jsp

```
CQ.WCM.launchSidekick("<%= xssAPI.getValidHref(currentPage.getPath()) %>", {
    propsDialog: "<%= dlgPath == null ? "" : xssAPI.getValidHref(dlgPath) %>",
    locked: <%= currentPage.isLocked() %>
});
```

In case, you want the sidekick to be unavailable only under specific conditions, you can listen to the `sidekickready` event fired by the [CQ.WCM](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.WCM) class as shown below, and then hide the sidekick.

```
CQ.Ext.onReady(function(){
    var top = CQ.WCM.getTopWindow();
    if (top.CQ.WCM.isSidekickReady()) {
        top.CQ.WCM.getSidekick().hide();
    } else {
        top.CQ.WCM.on("sidekickready", function(sidekick) {
            sidekick.hide();
        });
    }
});
```

**EDIT - Explaining the lengthy code**

The above script is written to work in any component without issues, not just the `init.jsp`.

The `CQ.Ext.onReady` is to execute our code after the DOM is ready.
`CQ.WCM.getTopWindow()` fetches the top most window. In case our script is executed after the sidekick is ready, then the `sidekickready` event would have been fired already and hence our code might not execute.

Hence we first check if the sidekick is already available using `top.CQ.WCM.isSidekickReady()` and in case it isn't, we attach a listener to the `sidekickready` event, so that we are notified when it is ready.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used the second option, but I'm curious why it's so long, and wondering if all those things are necessary. Can you edit your answer and explain how that javascript works? Thanks.

Comment: @JamesWatkins Included the details :)

Comment: So am I safe in executing only 'CQ.WCM.on("sidekickready", ... { sk.hide() });' If I put it in a particular location? such as, just after init.jsp?

Comment: @JamesWatkins. If it is init.jsp, then I think it is fine.

Comment: FYI, there are some situations where this solution doesn't work, even with the full code snippet. I haven't investigated why exactly, but I settled on overlaying the init.jsp because nothing else worked.

Comment: Very Safe and beautiful piece of code. Works really well.